# Scheduled Task keeps creating dllhost processes

Tags: cpu, powershell, process, scheduled-tasks, dll

I have a scheduled task that runs a Powershell script that sends an http request. This task is ran under a service account. Every time the task runs, it creates a dllhost process, which eventually takes up a lot of CPU. This only happens when the script is ran under the service account. Is there a setting in Task Scheduler that would close this process when it is done?

Edit:
This is in Windows 10 and it is a custom script.

Comment: Can you tell us the name of the task in question, is it a custom script? Also are you using Windows 10, which flavor? __A task should alway release a dllhost process when it is finished.__

Comment: @vssher I added those details. And yes, the task releases the dllhost process when ran under a different account. The service account runs other scripts too. Some sort of combination of the script and the service account causes this.